# What are some good relative regression metrics?

Tags: predictive-models, boosting, error, loss-functions, metric

- Which **relative** regression metrics exist?
- What are their strengths and weaknesses?
- In what case do you use each?

--> Bonus point if they are already/easily implemented in Scikit-Learn.

I have a regression problem with varying predicted scales. I basically have data from 3 machines (small, medium, big) that I may either consider all together, or split per machine. At first, I thought making one model per machine would help, as it would reduced the noise, so I started with the big machine, having the most data. Then, I grouped all machines' data and my $R^2$ score, as well as my Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE) improved.

Now I am wondering:

- Did the algorithm (XGBRegressor) manage to figure out on its own what is common and what is different between the three machines? That would mean that my model does actually perform better.
- Are the improved results just an illusion caused by the inclusion of smaller machines?
  *I.e.* smaller machines $\implies$ smaller production $\implies$ smaller errors, even though my model does not actually perform better.

So I am thinking that using relative errors in order to fix that potential optical illusion. What are your thoughts on that? What are some appropriate metrics?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What constitutes a relative error, something like [mean absolute percentage error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_percentage_error)?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean by relative. I.e. it compares the error with the value of `y_true`